# React Native Expo with Bugsnag Sourcemaps bugsnag-eas-build-on-success Not found

Tags: react-native, expo, source-maps, bugsnag

I am trying to get sourcemaps to work on an expo 49 project.

the [bugsnag docs](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/expo/manual-setup/) say to add this to package.json

```
  "scripts": {
      ...
      "eas-build-on-success": "npx bugsnag-eas-build-on-success"
  }
```

However whenever building via `$ eas build -p ios` I get this error:

```
404 Not Found - GET https://registry.yarnpkg.com/bugsnag-eas-build-on-success - Not found
```

I've searched yarn and npm and this package (bugsnag-eas-build-on-success) doesn't seem to exist. Any help would be greatly appreciated!